# iOS - AVPlayer seekToTime to a backward (HLS) position not working sometimes

Tags: ios, avfoundation, h.264, avplayer

I did not find any solution to my problem yet and hope someone can help me.

**Given:**

- AVPlayer instance with an AVUrlAsset (HTTP Live Stream)
- m3u8 spec:

  ```
  EXT-X-VERSION:3
  EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT

  #EXTINF:0.96000, 178200
  segment-00000.ts
  ```
- Each segment starts with an IDR frame (therefore .ts are aligned, at least i hope that)
- seekTo used with CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(timescale=1), kCMTimeZero accuracy
- currentPlayerItem.duration and asset.duration have the infinity flag set
- Let's assume we are at second 100 of 200 and we want to seek one second forward and one second backward

**Problem:**

- seekTo seeks fardward (always) and backward (**not** always)
- it seemes there are specific framepositions where the backward seeking operation only decrements the currentTime!! value of the AVPlayer instance but nothing else
- I seek backwards (-1 second) many times and the player shows an old picture
- After I seeked many many times (while seeing the wrong position) the player continues to  really seek backwards eventually. But now currentTime is like -40seconds and PTS of the showed picture is like -3seconds.
- info: seekTo does complete and the completionHandler gets called with finished=YES, always!
- info2: same problems with kCMTimeIndefinite accuracy

**Questions**

- What can be the cause of that problem?
- What kind of frames may be affected?
- After seeking: Why AVPlayer does not know when it presents an old PTS... Otherwise AVPlayer would not set currentTime to a newer position.
- Do i need to seek to the middle between two segments? e.g. 0.96 second, or can i just use CMTimeMakeWithSecond(1,1) in that case?

Best reagards!

Code requested by a user:

```
AVPlayer* avPlayerStart = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
_mStartPlayer = avPlayerStart;

[_mPreviewStartView setPlayer:_mStartPlayer];

AVURLAsset* anAssest= [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];

_mCurrentPlayerItemStart = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:anAssest];
[_mStartPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_mCurrentPlayerItemStart];

//operation:
taggingStart -= 1;
[_mStartPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(taggingStart, 1) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

Comment: Could you show us your code, please?

Comment: When having issues with seeking, in most cases, the problem lies within the encoding of the video. The higher the i-frame frequency is in your video, the more accurate you will be able to seek.

Comment: Hi @Till, I also fear that this can be the reason. But I'm not 100% sure. I'll try it with another stream (more keyframes) later. Unfortunately the stream is captured from a device where it's not possible to set the GOP-size (Blackmagic H.264 Pro Recorder).

Comment: Hi @Neeku, sorry, but I think everything code related is explained above.

Comment: You still need to show your bit of code so that we can provide you a helpful answer. (:

Comment: @Neeku, first part: initialization, second part: seeking operation (backward). The other part (View) is really unimportant for us.

Comment: Great Bastian. That looks much better now. (: